# Get specific columns and aggregate with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get some columns with pandas, then trying to aggregate. Here is my code:

```
mostspent = df.groupby(['Customer ID'])
mostspent.agg({"VALUE":sum}).sort_values(by="VALUE", ascending=False)

            VALUE
Customer ID 
HETX        60332.00
DOWY        17234.50
HEXZ        17070.20
```

But I also want to get Customer Name column too, But I didn't success.

Answer (score 0):

You can try grouping by two columns: 'Customer ID' and 'Customer Name'

i.e `df.groupby(['Customer ID', 'Customer Name'])`

Comment: And, I discovered something now, if I do {"VALUE":sum} I see some customers' sum of value are 0. It's error.

Comment: if I do groupby().sum() or agg('sum') it sums everything numeric inside but returns true result.